# Rigify to Unity converter stretches 3d model in blender

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, rigify

My 3d model animations works perfectly in blender. But whenever I use "Rigify to Unity Converter" addon it stretches the mesh as if it was pinned at a certain point(T-pose hand and foot position). How can I fix such a problem?

[image]